# still didn't get the call command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call

Here is my mk.exe is in folder1, but after loader2.bat finishes its job, it doesn't pass control to my loader1.bat and mk.exe isn't executing.

```
@echo off
cd folder1\folder2
call Loader2.bat
mk.exe /s
```

My Loader2.bat

```
@echo off
DXSETUP.exe
echo Installing DirectX ... PLease Wait...
PhysX.exe /s
echo Installing PhysX ... Please Wait...
PhysXL.exe /s
echo Installing PhysX Legacy ... Please Wait...
vc.exe /s
echo Installing VC Redistributable ... Please Wait...
exit
```

Comment: Can you post `loader2.bat`?

Comment: Change `exit` to `exit /b`

Comment: I added /b after exit but still nothing happens,

Answer (score 0):

If you `exit` it ends the process. To avoid this, we use `goto :eof` or just hit the end of the file.

Change **Loader2.bat** to:

```
@echo off
DXSETUP.exe
echo Installing DirectX ... PLease Wait...
PhysX.exe /s
echo Installing PhysX ... Please Wait...
PhysXL.exe /s
echo Installing PhysX Legacy ... Please Wait...
vc.exe /s
echo Installing VC Redistributable ... Please Wait...
```

and the call function should act as you desire.

Comment: tried ghoto :eof and tried also the above mentioned, its my bad luck nothing happened.